# Problems with Powering Led Project Through Vin Pin

Tags: led, esp8266, nodemcu

I am working on lighting some WS2812 Leds with a nodemcu form hiLetgo. The project works when it is powered from the usb that is on the board, but as soon as it is powered from the barrel jack, the leds will only light up to the last color that they were set, ignoring code. A schematic and code are included for reference.[image: The schematic]

```c
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

// Which pin on the ESP8266 is connected to the NeoPixels?
#define PIN            D8

// How many NeoPixels are attached to the ESP8266?
#define NUMPIXELS      30

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

int delayval = 10; // delay for half a second
int x, y, z;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pixels.begin(); // This initializes the NeoPixel library.
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  z = 0;
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
   for(int i=0;i<NUMPIXELS;i++){
    x = (x+1)%256;
    // pixels.Color takes RGB values, from 0,0,0 up to 255,255,255

    pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(x,y,z)); // Moderately bright green color.

    pixels.show(); // This sends the updated pixel color to the hardware.

    delay(delayval); // Delay for a period of time (in milliseconds).

  }
  y= (y+1)%256;

}
```

Comment: can you confirm that the code is actually running when powered from  barrel jack

Comment: I have tested it with other code that shows that the code runs when powered form the barrel jack.

Comment: What voltage are you providing through the barrel jack?

Comment: 5v according to the power brick, but according to my multi it's more like 5.2 - 5.3v. Also, it is rated at 3a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: What is the purpose of that resistor you have in there? It serves no purpose as far as I can see, and would only cause problems anyway. Lose it.

Second: You have logic voltage level problems:

- You are supplying 5.2V to the LEDs.
- The ESP8266 is a 3.3V device.
- The ESP8266 outputs 3.3V as a logic HIGH.
- The WS2812 accepts 0.7Vdd as logic HIGH (as stated in [the datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf)).
- **0.7 × 5.2 = 3.64v**

Ergo, the LEDs aren't seeing the logic HIGH signal as logic HIGH because it is too low a voltage.

Add to that the voltage drop across the resistor and your logic HIGH voltage will be even less.

So:

1. Lose the pointless resistor
2. Either reduce the supply voltage to the LEDs or increase the output HIGH voltage level with a logic level shifter circuit (3.3v -> 5v).

Comment: According to Sparkfun (https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/ws2812-breakout-hookup-guide) it is important to use the resistor to protect the data pin.

Comment: @user3242816 They're talking gibberish. Protect it from what?!

Comment: My assumption was from excessive current draw, but I'm relatively new to the hardware side of electronics.

Comment: The only effect you would see from that resistor is a slight voltage drop and a low-pass filter formed with the input capacitance of the data pin that limits the maximum frequency you could use. There is nothing to draw excess current, since there is no fan-out, only a 1:1 connection from a low-impedance output to a high impedance input.

Comment: Interesting. I gave bypassing the resistor with a piece of wire a shot and now it works. Thank you for your advice!